# how to create new build tool sdk in windows

Tags: android, windows, sdk, react-native

I have the API version 26 of Android sdk on my windows directory:`C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platforms` and some other versions like:

```
android-23
android-25
android-26
```

but in `build-tools` folder, i only have a folder named `23.0.3`. it means i don't have build tool of another versions. so how can i have `26.0.2` or `26.0.2` in this folder. because now i can just targeting 23 build version for my `react-native` apps. but i need to target higher versions.

Answer (score 1):

You have to install them with the SDK Manager (more info at https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/update.html#sdk-manager) or with the sdkmanager command line tool (more info at https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/sdkmanager.html).

For example, with sdkmanager use:

```
sdkmanager --list
```

To get available packages and then for example:

```
sdkmanager build-tools;26.0.2
```

To install build-tools 26.0.2.